# How do I fix the e90002 error raised by System.Xml.ni.dll?

Tags: windows-10

I've been getting an error e90002 whenever I log into Windows from System.Xml.ni.dll. I searched for a way to resolve this, which brought me to this link: https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-fix-system-xml-ni-dll-errors-in-windows/

The first thing this suggests doing is running RegSrv32 from a command prompt. I tried both a Command prompt and PowerShell, but both failed. They both failed because this machine is Microsoft Surface running Windows 10 in S-Mode, so the Cmd and PowerShell are blocked to users. Other links I've found suggest similar ways of fixing this, so they're not helpful. I've tried running Microsoft Defender on the Surface, but I can't. I might be able to, but it isn't obvious to me how to run Defender on the Surface. When I try, I'm presented with a means of seeing how Defender is set up, but not a way of scanning the machine.

So, how do I fix System.Xml.ni.dll on Windows 10 in S-Mode?

Comment: So go with `regsvr32 /u "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.dll"` first and then follow that with `regsvr32 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.dll"`. It might also be worth a computer restart, check Windows Updates are full installed and install the latest if not, running the `sfc /scannow` and perhaps running the .[Net framework repair tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30135) and running it.